# How come PHP's in_array() method recognizes the existence of a specific instance of an object, in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I came across something interesting: in_array() function doesn't just work when the "needle" is a specific value, but also when it's a specific object instance. I'll give an example:

```
class Message{
  private $str;
  function __construct($str){
      $this->str= $str;
  }

}

$message1 = new Message('Hey there!');

$message2 = new Message('sup');

$message3 = new Message('yo');

$arr= [$message2, 545,'hey'];

echo in_array($message2 ,$arr) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

As you can see, i'm creating different instances of some class. A reference to one of these instances is placed into an array.

When i check the existence of "message2" object in the array, i get **true**. if i change needle to be "message1" or "message3", i'll get **false**.

How does this work? The documentation says it "Checks if a value exists in an array". **But is a reference to an object a "value"?** Can someone clarify this issue?

Comment: There are no object references here. The difference is the private variable `$str`. Make the strings identical and they will all work.

Comment: Yes i did this experiment now, and you're right. So it basically performs a deep comparison of some kind?

Comment: An object reference is a value like anything else. Anything you can assign to a variable is a value.

Comment: There's no deep comparison going on. It's no different from `if ($message2 == $message2)`.

Comment: Loose comparison : `Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same class.` Strict comparison : `Object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.` `in_array()` without 3rd argument to TRUE will do a loose comparison.

Comment: Probably should answer it @Lou...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php):

> As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

Before the days of "OOP" PHP (i.e. PHP < 5), all variables were passed by *value*. You could always pass a variable by reference by using the `&` operator, though this is not the same as a language like C which uses pointers. In PHP5+, objects aren't passed by reference, but an object variable doesn't contain the object itself, rather an identifier to the object. When you pass that variable to a function a copy of that identifier is sent as the argument, just like any other primitive.

The most important thing to understand is that when you pass an object to a function, the object itself is not passed, but rather an identifier to an object. These identifiers provide access to the object itself, while still allowing you to do array searches and equality comparisons (`===`) between instances.

While the PHP docs are a bit cryptic, we can see that the object identifier is in fact a value:

> the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

The value of a variable containing an object is the object identifier, not the object itself.

```
// $obj contains an identifier to an instance of `MyObject`
$obj = new MyObject();
```

When you pass `$obj` to a function, a *copy* of that identifier is sent as the argument. PHP **always passes a variable by its value**, unless explicitly instructed to pass by reference using `&$var`. So, to answer your question, a reference (or rather, *identifier*) to an object is in fact a value that can be used for comparing specific instances of an object.

---

**Edit**

As @Chris Anderson and @Lou pointed out, `in_array` does loose comparison by default. When comparing two objects, `==`checks that they are the same instance and have the same attribute values, while `===` checks they are an instance of the same class. Unless I am misunderstanding, your original question was asking about the nature of how a variable storing an instance of a class behaves, so my original answer should suffice for the question at hand. However, it *is* important to note that without explicitly asking for strict comparison (`===`), you will get `true` if the object's values are identical.

Comment: I see, but that still doesn't explain the fact, that if i send the same argument to my Message class's constructor, in two different instances, in_array would return true, even though i'm comparing two different objects. I've tried it, and AbraCadaver is right.

Comment: That's not what your original question was. You didn't even know that was possible until `AbraCadaver` mentioned it in the comments...it has nothing to do with your original question... @sheff2k1

Comment: Yeah well, it seems i sort of mixed two different issues here together. But now, all is clear :D

Comment: All good, I think AbraCadaver might have misunderstood the question, but he brought up an important point!

Answer (score 2):

Ref: [Comparing Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php)

```
class Message{
    private $str;
    function __construct($str){
      $this->str= $str;
    }
}

$message1 = new Message('Hey there!');
$message2 = new Message('yo');
$message3 = new Message('yo');

$arr = [$message2, 545,'hey'];
//loose comparison using == 
echo in_array($message3 ,$arr) ? 'true' : 'false'; // returns true

//strict comparison using ===
echo in_array($message3 ,$arr, true) ? 'true' : 'false'; // returns false
```

**in_array()**

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

> Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is set.

**Loose Comparison(==) :**

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are compared in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values (values are compared with ==), and are instances of the same class.

**Strict Comparison(===):**

> When using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.